# Service Temporarily Unavailable error when I try to acces a spacebrew server using nodejs?

Tags: apache-2.2, node.js, openshift-online-2, 503-error, openshift-origin

I've tried to install Spacebrew for an Arduino Yun project on a 'openshift' nodejs server, but get the following error when I go to the url:

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at spacebrew-cuebo.rhcloud.com Port 80
```

I tried to restart, but no luck. If I log in to the server and see the dir.log I get the following message:

```
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at net.js:1143:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
warn: [Restart] the spacebrew server has been restarted 1584 time
Running Spacebrew, start with argument '--help' to see available configuration arguments.
More info at http://www.spacebrew.cc
```

Openshift run the following version of node:
Node.js 0.10

I'm not sure what the problem is or how I can fix it?

Comment: I think the error message is quite explanatory, no? `Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.` - The service is temporarily unavailable, so you'd be best trying again later when the service has potentially been restored.

Comment: I just dont understand the error log in to the file.log? Is it just that simple, that I should be patient?

Comment: I can't say for sure - but you have at least one verifiable and serious error in the form of the unavailable service, so I suggest waiting until that service is restored and see whether the remaining errors are resolved as a result.

Comment: What do you mean with 'at least one verifiable and serious error in the form of the unavailable service'?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I can make it any plainer - as per the first error message, the service you are trying to connect to is down. Wait until it is no longer down, and see if you are able to install your package(s) as intended.